# ¿Cómo eliminar última coma en foreach de Blade?

Tags: laravel-blade

Tengo el siguiente código, yo separo con una coma cada etiqueta... Pero el último dato también se muestra con una coma

```
@foreach($post->tags as $tag)
    <a href="{{ route('tag', $tag->slug) }}">{{ $tag->name }}</a>,
@endforeach
```

¿cómo puedo evitarlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar la variable `$loop`:

```
@foreach($post->tags as $tag)
    <a href="{{ route('tag', $tag->slug) }}">{{ $tag->name }}</a>{{ $loop->last ? '': ',' }}
@endforeach
```